# Router in front of Bell modem drops out TV

Tags: router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

Ok, I live in Toronto, Canada, and I signed up for Bell's FibeTV service (includes phone & Internet ofc).

They had their wireless router sit in my living room which is connected to their Modem in the basement via ethernet cable.

But these Bell routers don't really have a good signal strength, so I decided to buy a router. I ended up purchasing a D-Link DIR-815 DUAL N600.

I followed the steps here: http://www.labnol.org/software/add-router-to-wireless-network/

I have an ethernet cable going from the modem in the basement, to the internet port of the BELL router (now in the basement also). Then from the LAN port of BELL router, the ethernet cable goes up to my living room and into a free LAN port in my D-Link router. Then, from another free LAN port on D-Link to the Bell TV Box Ethernet port.

Internet browsing is just fine; however, the TV now says "Television signal has been lost."

If I change channel, the picture appears but after a few seconds I get the message again.

Is my D-Link router not fast enough? i.e. do I need a gigabit router, maybe?

***UPDATE*** If I take the ethernet cable out of the D-Link (the one coming from Bell Router downstairs) and plug directly into Bell TV box, I get uninterrupted TV. The D-Link router is definitely the choking point it seems. Question is... is it configuration or hardware?

Comment: The settings look about right to me. There's a third possibility - that the TV box is detecting whether or not its a bell router and disconnecting you. I'd connect a PC to the d-link router just to see whats going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traffic is separated onto virtual LANs (VLAN), internet traffic is on VLAN 35 and Bell Fibe TV traffic is on VLAN 36. The Bell router handles this while the stock D-LINK DIR-815 doesn't.

Set things up so TV traffic doesn't have to go through the DLINK and it should be fine.